# Dependency Injection with Ninject and Global Filter: IAuthorizationFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, filter, ninject, ninject.web

I use standart NinjectMVC3 Bootstrapper installed in the App_Start folder.

My application class looks like:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        // ... routes here ...
    }

    public void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        // empty
    }
}
```

I have only following bidding rules registed in NinjectMVC3:

```
Bind<IAccountsRepository>().To<AccountsRepository>();
this.BindFilter<GlobalAuthFilter>(FilterScope.Global, 0);
```

And my global filter:

```
public class GlobalAuthFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    readonly IAccountsRepository _accountsRepository;

    public GlobalAuthFilter(IAccountsRepository accountsRepository)
    {
        _accountsRepository = accountsRepository;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        // Code here never reached. Why? What's wrong?
    }
}
```

There are any controllers in my application. And I want to invoke OnAuthorization for every action calls for every controllers.

But my code dosn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite clear from your code where more specifically are you configuring your kernel. This should be done in the `RegisterServices` method of `~/App_Start/NinjectMVC3.cs`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Load your modules or register your services here!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IAccountsRepository>().To<AccountsRepository>();
    kernel.BindFilter<GlobalAuthFilter>(FilterScope.Global, 0);
}
```

When you install the `Ninject.MVC3` NuGet package the body of this method will be empty and it is where you should either directly configure dependencies or define Ninject modules that you would import in this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Load your modules or register your services here!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Load(new MyModule());
}
```

where you have defined the custom module:

```
public class MyModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<IAccountsRepository>().To<AccountsRepository>();
        this.BindFilter<GlobalAuthFilter>(FilterScope.Global, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I placed binding rules in RegisterServices. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @JeanLouis, I have just tested this code and it worked perfectly fine. Steps: 1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application. 2. Install the Ninject.MVC3 NuGet package. 3. Define the `IAccountsRepository`, `AccountsRepository` and `GlobalAuthFilter` types. 4. Put the code I have shown in my answer in the RegisterServices method. 5. Run the application. 6. The OnAuthorization is executed.

Comment: I have updated my answer to illustrate an example with Ninject modules.

Comment: Yes you are right. So I have another error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't forget the `BindFilter<T>()` is an extension method located in `Ninject.Web.Mvc.FilterBindingSyntax`

Comment: Isn't it bad idea to register global filters in "ninject config", insted of using FilterConfig?