# Resolving dependencies in Global.asax if an IoC container is initialized through WebActivator

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control, ninject

In an ASP.NET MVC3 application, I initialize a Ninject IoC container through a

```
[assembly : WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod( typeof (NinjectMVC3), "Start" )]
```

A class `NinjectMVC3` is responsible for my IoC container `Kernel` initialization.

After this is called, all controllers, that declare resolvable dependencies through a constructor variables get them resolved just fine.

But I need to use a resolved dependency in `Global.asax` `Application_Start` method, to feed it to some Custom Global Filters of mine? How can I resolve dependencies in `Application_Start` in my scenario?

Comment: See also this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079228/dependency-injection-with-ninject-and-global-filter-iauthorizationfilter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should choose a different way. Inject the dependencies directly to your filters instead of assigning them to the global asax first. This way you solve two problems at once:

1. The global asax does not need to know about those dependencies that it does not need itsself. You should avoid to have dependencies on objects that are just there to pass them on to other components whenever you can directly assign them to this object.
2. You don't need to use Property injection or service location to get them into the global asax

The documentation of the Ninject.MVC3 extensions shows how you can create the filters using Ninject so that you can do constructor injection for them:

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Dependency-injection-for-filters

Comment: This is indeed a better solution. Nifty!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<T>()`